# Using a shell to run a bot in java

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, irc

Hello I recently got a shell from http://shellmix.com/index.php/free-account/free-shell-account and I set it up and all. So then I put my bot (pircbot coded with Eclipse in Java) in Filezilla and http://pastebin.com/suJDwJfu is what I have done so far in putty. I just want it to host my bot and have it online always. My code runs fine in Eclipse so I put it in a .jar and changed the meta.inf to be working fine. And now I just need help running it. So please look at my errors and tell me what to do.

Edit:
I fixed my manifest thing so now I get this error: http://pastebin.com/EuK5P6Lv

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException when trying to run .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368349/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-jar-file)

Comment: @user1938490 Regarding your [latest edit's stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/EuK5P6Lv), you should either add the `org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot` library to your classpath (refer to `java -cp` (see `java -h`)) or package the Pircbot code into your .jar.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the following:

1. You have a static main method:

   `public static void main(String[] args) { 
       //Your code to run
   }`
2. You have exported the jar using **Eclipse->Export->Runnable Jar** and chose the specific `main` function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the public static void main in my Main class, but it is     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Comment: Main can't throw an exception because no one will catch it.
Also export your project as **Runnable Jar**

Answer (score 1):

Your class must have `public static void main(String args[])` method, which means you can execute the class from the commandline.

This does not make it the jar's main execution class, however. The main class is set in **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**. Normally it should have a line:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

but then with the actual class.

So open the jar with a zip program, and check **MANIFEST.MF**.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_10-rc (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: VortexBotMain
Class-Path: pircbot.jar VortexBotMain.jar