# executing jar file through cmd

Tags: java, jar

I have created a folder named "Thank" in c drive and in that folder, I have 2 java files namely T1 and myApp.

```
class T1 { 
    void display() {
        System.out.println("Hey I am working");
    }
}
```

and

```
class myApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        T1 t=new T1();
        t.display(); 
    }
}
```

Now I created a jar file of this folder by:

```
 c:\>jar cf myApp.jar Thank
```

This creates a Jar file named myApp.

I even wrote `Main-Class: myApp in the manifest.mf file`.

When I try to run this by:

```
c:\>java -jar myApp.jar
```

I get an error -

> An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file
>   myApp.jar

Please tell me how to run jar file so that I get an output:

```
Hey I am working
```

Comment: have a look.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368349/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-jar-file

Comment: What does your complete manifest file look like and where is it stored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Jar file in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

Comment: @tbsalling myApp.jar is stored in c drive. It further has 2 folders namely: META-INF & Thank. META-INF has a MANIFEST.MF file which contains:    Main-Class: myApp;

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: I have updated my answer below, showing how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `jar cfm myApp.jar manifest.txt *.class` to create the jar, so that the manifest file gets located correctly in the jar.

The right location of the manifest is `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

### **Update**

I have made your code work, basically by taking the files you had prepared; adding a package declaration to the java files and the manifest, and upper-casing the MyApp class from myApp. The files are arranged in this folder structure:

```
tbsmac:17162802-executing-java-file-through-cmd tbsalling$ ls -lR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 tbsalling  staff  102 19 Jun 18:48 META-INF
drwxr-xr-x  4 tbsalling  staff  136 19 Jun 18:57 thank

./META-INF:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 tbsalling  staff  46 19 Jun 18:49 MANIFEST.MF

./thank:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 tbsalling  staff  124 19 Jun 18:49 MyApp.java
-rw-r--r--  1 tbsalling  staff   98 19 Jun 18:48 T1.java
```

The contents of the three files are:

**MyApp.java:**

```
package thank;

class MyApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      T1 t=new T1();
      t.display(); 
    }
}
```

**T1.java:**

```
package thank;

class T1 { 
   void display() {
    System.out.println("Hey I am working");
   }
}
```

**MANIFEST.MF:**

```
Main-Class: thank.MyApp
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Then I run this series of commands:

```
tbsmac:17162802-executing-java-file-through-cmd tbsalling$ javac thank/T1.java thank/MyApp.java 
tbsmac:17162802-executing-java-file-through-cmd tbsalling$ jar cfm myApp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF thank/*.class
tbsmac:17162802-executing-java-file-through-cmd tbsalling$ java -jar myApp.jar 
Hey I am working
```

^^^ and it works ;-)

Comment: Should I replace "MyApp.class" with "*" ?

Answer (score 0):

try by typing: java.exe -jar "(full path to jar)"

example: java.exe -jar "C:\TestFolder\Project Java\myApp.jar"

Comment: It again says that an unexpected error occurs while opening c:\myApp.jar

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Make sure you add the complete class name along with package names in manifest file.
2. Also make sure to add a newline at the end of your jar manifest file. If not do so.