# Intellij Idea Swing designer and ant build

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created an application using the intellij-idea gui designer for swing and when i'm launch with ide all works fine.
But when i'm creating jar file using ant the swings components doesn't launch.
Below the "java -jar" output.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fr.upem.matou.hmi.Chat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at fr.upem.matou.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Have you an idea ?

Regards

Comment: I can't give a proper answer since I don't use Intellij IDEA or Ant myself, but I think this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368349/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-jar-file

Comment: No that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use gui under intelliJ Idea is:

1. Using JFormDesigner (inside);
2. Free. Using Netbeans matisse in parrallel mode (with winmerge for example);
3. Free. Writing all gui code by hands.

Post here ant configuration. Some component is not found.
Problem reason in different build configs.
Also you can try to build with maven (the best way).